# Freezing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of freezing your Rails version/gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799416/whats-the-point-of-freezing-your-rails-version-gems)

What does it mean to freeze a gem (in Rails 2.3)?

And how do you do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `rake` task that unpacks the gems referenced in `config/environment.rb` into `vendor/gems` but his method was never very reliable and has been deprecated in favor of the new [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) system using `Gemfile`.

The biggest issue with freezing gems was that compiled gems, or gems with system dependencies would never be frozen properly. Only pure-ruby gems could be properly archived.